# self contained linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I created a linked list in this method...

```
class stack
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node *link;
    }*top;

void insert()
{ ... }

void display()
{ ... }

};
```

and it works fine... Now i am trying to do the same operations with a self contained linked list but I end up with error. This is my code

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element(const std::string& str)
    {
        head = NULL;
        head -> data = str;
    }
    void Append(const Element& elem)
    {
        node *newnode;
        newnode=new node;
        newnode->data = elem;
        node *target=head;

        while(target->next != NULL)
            target = target->next;

        target -> next = newnode;
    }

private:
    struct node
    {
        string data;
        node *next;
    }*head;
};

void main()
{   
    Element *root = new Element("Hello");

    root->Append(Element("World"));
}
```

I want to modify only my Element class, but I am not clear.

I may have done some silly mistake in my program, because I am new to data structures and I am confused by online references.

Comment: `main` is required to have a return type of `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your design is wrong. I might be second guessing what your teacher meant, but I think the self contained list should look like this.

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element(const std::string& str)
    {
        data = str;
        next = NULL;
    }
    void Append(const Element& elem)
    {
        Element* tail = this;
        while (tail->next)
            tail = tail->next;
        tail->next = new Element(elem.data);
    }

private:
    string data;
    Element *next;
};
```

In other words `Element` is the node class. I think this is what you teacher meant by 'self contained linked list class', and 'Element is not a manager class'.

In the `main` code you where given notice how the start of the list is in the variable `root`. But you are trying to hold the start of the list in `Element::head` as well. So with your design the start of the list is being held in two places, which doesn't make a lot of sense. I don't think this is what you teacher intended, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I am sorry i couldn't make it... If Element is a node class, how should i respond to,
Element *root = new Element("Hello");
and
root->Append(Element("World"));

I am sorry I don't have any teacher to ask. My only way of learning is online, but I could not find any method for this type.

Comment: I understand the use of const in void Append(const Element& elem) and void print(int) const, but why do we use const here

Element(const std::string& str)

and without const here error occurs... why is that so?

Comment: and i could not print it normally like

cout<<data;

I have to do it like this

printf("%s\n", tail->data.c_str());

can you please explain...

Comment: If you can do `printf("%s\n", tail->data.c_str());` then you can also do `cout << tail->data;`. Why `cout << data;` didn't work I couldn't say unless I could see your code.

Comment: The reason that const is needed in `Element(const std::string& str)` is complicated. Too complicated to explain fully in a short comment I'm afraid. But when you write `Element("hello")` you are creating a temporary `std::string` object from the string literal `"hello"`, and that temporary cannot be bound to a non-const reference. I said it was complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor -

```
head = NULL;
head -> data = str;
```

Code has undefined behavior. You should not access members on a NULL pointer. After `head` pointing to a proper memory location, you should also do -

```
head -> next = NULL;
```

in the constructor for the append operation to reliably work. I think `Element::Append` should receive the `std::string` parameter given that you are trying to do -

```
newnode->data = elem;
```